# Sorting products category wise

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables product, category

[image]

and product_category.

[image]

How to sort products, category wise and get the category name as well joining the table product_category to category, since the product_category has only cat_id and no category name.

```
Cell Pones
Cell Pones 1
Cell Pones 2
Cell Pones 3

Books
Book 1
Book 2
Book 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all product/category combinations and sort them by category name. Obviously products and categories can occur more than once because the relationship product-category is many-to-many.

```
SELECT p.prd_name, p.prd_price, c.cat_name
FROM Product p
JOIN Product_category pc ON p.prd_id = pc.prd_id
JOIN Category c ON c.cat_id = pc.cat_id
ORDER BY c.cat_name
```

Comment: hey thanks for answering .... i see it's working, but can you please explain what p in p.prd_name, c in c.cat_name, pc in product_category and c in c on c.cat_id means?.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a "relational" output, because the column has different meanings and the position of the rows is important (SQL result sets and tables usually represent unordered sets).  But, you can do it.

```
select name
from ((select cat_id, cat_name as name, 0 as sortorder
       from category_table
      ) union all
      (select cat_id, prd_name, 1 as sortorder
       from product_category pc join
            product p
            on pc.prd_id = p.prd_id
      )
     ) n
order by cat_id, sortorder;
```